# Change Discount Label in PDF Invoice in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.6

In Magento-2 I generate PDF invoice and successfully edit the layout of PDF.
There is one More thing to change the label of Discount

Current Label is **Discount(Coupon Code)**
want change in **Discount(Coupon Code -inclusive tax)**

I already try many things like (1) change in en_US.csv but it doesn't work with me

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by following method as pdf discount section cannot be managed by csv. 
If you check the code then you will like below which not supports translations(i18n):

```
$title = __($this->getTitle());
if ($this->getTitleSourceField()) {
    $label = $title . ' (' . $this->getTitleDescription() . '):';
} else {
    $label = $title . ':';
}
```

So you need to modify that section.

**OR**

If you are using single language then do the following:

Override **DefaultTotal.php** by adding following line to your module's **di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\DefaultTotal" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\DefaultTotal" />
```

And create **DefaultTotal.php** under

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Model/Order/Pdf/Total/DefaultTotal.php

and add the below code:

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Model\Order\Pdf\Total;

class DefaultTotal extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\DefaultTotal
{
    public function getTotalsForDisplay()
    {
        $amount = $this->getOrder()->formatPriceTxt($this->getAmount());
        if ($this->getAmountPrefix()) {
            $amount = $this->getAmountPrefix() . $amount;
        }

        $title = __($this->getTitle());
        if ($this->getTitleSourceField()) {
            if($title == 'Discount'){
                $label = $title . ' (' . $this->getTitleDescription() . ' -inclusive tax):';
            }
            else{
                $label = $title . ' (' . $this->getTitleDescription() . '):';   
            }
        } else {
            $label = $title . ':';
        }

        $fontSize = $this->getFontSize() ? $this->getFontSize() : 7;
        $total = ['amount' => $amount, 'label' => $label, 'font_size' => $fontSize];
        return [$total];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You for your time and your answer, it works fine with me.....

Answer (score 0):

Try adding adding your translation strings to your file theme :

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/i18n/en_US.csv
```

Like this :

```
"Grand Total","Big Total"
```

*Note : be careful with spaces at the end of some translations*

Comment: it was reflected in only Admin Panel, not in PDF invoice, I also need to change in PDF invoice.